# Excel: Creating Unique Indentifiers

Tags: excel

I'm looking to create a unique identifier column for a table in excel based on a few criteria. I've attached a picture with an example table below for reference.

Example excel table

[image]

What I'm looking to create is something like the third column "Unique ID", however, I'm having a hard time given the criteria I need to meet:

- 1. The ID needs to begin with the first letter of the "Category"
- 2. Each categories ID needs to begin at 1 when it's first introduced but continue where it left off when its re-introduced.
- 3. If a category has the same "Type", the "Unique ID" needs to create some kind of addition subset id such as ".1", "a", etc.

If anyone has any suggestions I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is located at `B2:C23`

To generate Unique Id's use these *Formulas Array*

*Enter the FormulaArray pressing* `[Ctrl]` *+* `[Shift]` *+* `[Enter]` *simultaneously, you shall see* `{` *and* `}` *around the formula if entered correctly*

Format `A#.#` Results at `D3:D23`

Enter Formula Array at `D3` the copy till `D23`

```
=IF(-1+COUNTIFS($B$2:$B3,$B3,$C$2:$C3,$C3)=0,
CONCATENATE(UPPER(LEFT($B3)),COUNTIF($B$2:$B3,$B3)),
CONCATENATE(
IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D2,
1-ROW($B$2)
+SMALL(IF(($B$2:$B$23=$B3)*($C$2:$C$23=$C3)=0,"",ROW($B$2:$B$23)),1)),""),
".",-1+COUNTIFS($B$2:$B3,$B3,$C$2:$C3,$C3)))
```

Format `A#.a` Results at `E3:E23`

Enter Formula Array at `E3` the copy till `E23`

```
=IF(-1+COUNTIFS($B$2:$B3,$B3,$C$2:$C3,$C3)=0,
CONCATENATE(UPPER(LEFT($B3)),COUNTIF($B$2:$B3,$B3)),
CONCATENATE(
IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:$E2,
1-ROW($B$2)
+SMALL(IF(($B$2:$B$23=$B3)*($C$2:$C$23=$C3)=0,"",ROW($B$2:$B$23)),1)),""),
".",CHAR(96+-1+COUNTIFS($B$2:$B3,$B3,$C$2:$C3,$C3))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot this was very helpful.